# Syntax Error: Unexpected Token

Tags: javascript, syntax-error, token

rookie coder here!

I'm learning on codeacademy.org and keep getting this error even  though I'm pretty sure its been written correctly. Help?

```
// Declare a variable on line 3 called
// myCountry and give it a string value.
var myCountry = "Panama";
// Use console.log to print out the length of the variable myCountry.
console.log(.length myCountry);

// Use console.log to print out the first three letters of myCountry.
console.log(myCountry .subscript(0,3));
```

Comment: What language is this?

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems with your example:

```
console.log(.length myCountry)
```

isn't valid Javascript; you need

```
console.log(myCountry.length)
```

(`length` is a property of the variable `myCountry`).

Also, `subscript` isn't a JS function, you need `substring`.

Full example:

```
// Declare a variable on line 3 called
// myCountry and give it a string value.
var myCountry = "Panama";
// Use console.log to print out the length of the variable myCountry.
console.log(myCountry.length);

// Use console.log to print out the first three letters of myCountry.
console.log(myCountry.substring(0, 3));
```

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing that out. I can continue the tutorial now! Its great that you give of your time to help others learn, I hope to learn enough and help others the same way one day.

Answer (score 0):

This is the right answer

```
var myCountry = "myCountry";
console.log("myCountry".length);


var myCountry = "myCountry";
console.log("myCountry".substring(0,3) );
```